# Iterate into element array then multiply with any number?

Tags: php, arrays

If i have an array like this ?

```
[
0 => [
    'sheet' => 'SUB-ARYA'
    'int' => 1
    'supplier_name' => 'TON DONG A CORPORATION'
    'contract_no' => 'D606D17LS091'
    'coil_no' => 'DNA07X2B419011701A'
    'size' => '0.42MM X 101MM X COIL'
    'net' => 4.65
    'nama_file' => 'STO SUB JKT 08082017.xlsx'
]
1 => [
    'sheet' => 'SUB-ARYA'
    'int' => 2
    'supplier_name' => 'NAM KIM STEEL JOINT STOCK COMPANY'
    'contract_no' => 'N014P17LS044'
    'coil_no' => '03NKXTL170400423/30'
    'size' => '0.70MM X 151.8MM X COIL'
    'net' => 4.944
    'nama_file' => 'STO SUB JKT 08082017.xlsx'
]
2 => [
    'sheet' => 'SUB-ARYA'
    'int' => 3
    'supplier_name' => 'TON DONG A CORPORATION'
    'contract_no' => 'D000G57LS597'
    'coil_no' => 'DNA07X2B511051718A'
    'size' => '0.42MM X 101MM X COIL'
    'net' => 4.74
    'nama_file' => 'STO SUB JKT 08082017.xlsx'
]
3 => [
    'sheet' => 'SUB-ARYA'
    'int' => 4
    'supplier_name' => 'TON DONG A CORPORATION'
    'contract_no' => 'D000G37LS377'
    'coil_no' => 'DNA10X1B422051704A'
    'size' => '0.43MM X 101MM X COIL'
    'net' => 4.65
    'nama_file' => 'STO SUB JKT 08082017.xlsx'
]
4 => [
    'sheet' => 'SUB-ARYA'
    'int' => 5
    'supplier_name' => 'TON DONG A CORPORATION'
    'contract_no' => 'D000G37LS378'
    'coil_no' => 'DNA10X2A421051713A'
    'size' => '0.43MM X 93.5MM X COIL'
    'net' => 4.72
    'nama_file' => 'STO SUB JKT 08082017.xlsx'
]
]
```

Please see value in element `net`.
There is :

```
'net' => 4.65 // in 0 index
'net' => 4.944 // in 1 index
'net' => 4.74 // in 2 index
'net' => 4.65 // in 3 index
'net' => 4.72 // in 4 index
```

I need to manipulate them into integer form,

```
'net' => 4650 // in 0 index
'net' => 4944 // in 1 index
'net' => 4740 // in 2 index
'net' => 4650 // in 3 index
'net' => 4720 // in 4 index
```

How to create in simple way to do it ?
Please advise

Comment: Hint: `array_walk`, times `net` by `1000`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone add your comment as answer (-;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) (keep it stupid simple):

```
array_walk($yourArray, function (&$item, $key) {
    $item['net'] *= 1000;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this is a single foreach loop:

```
foreach($yourArray as $i=>$v) {
   $yourArray[$i]['net'] *= 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_map` to do this. Example:

```
function modify($el){
    // this trick will return whole element, instead of only modified one
    $t = $el;
    $t['net'] = $t['net'] * 1000;
    return $t;
}
$result = array_map("modify", $yourArray);
```

Comment: KISS: `$el['net'] *= 1000; return $el;` (-;

Comment: @Neodan the callback must return a modified copy of `$el`. The question asks to change the values of key `net` into the original array (or produce an array with the same structure).